# :How to install a package behind an overly restricted firewall

Tags: apt, debian-installer, deb, ppa

EDIT: I know I can download and install manually, but my question is different and not a duplicate.

At my company we have a sand-box area where we have Debian machines.  IT has white-listed *.debian.org to be able to install packages but this hasn't worked as some(many?most?) packages require a redirection to another domain.

In my case I'm currently trying to `$ apt-get install rabbitmq-server` and there's a list of about 30 .deb files that are blocked (dependencies).  There will likely be other packages to install and test too, so the question is not specifically with rabbitmq.

Pestering IT to add to the white-list would be never ending (who knows what other domains we would need in the future, and IT probably doesn't want to continually growing the list).

I could go fetch the .deb files and install them manually, each one.  But I'm concerned with the maintainability of this; I would have to repeat again instead of simply running `$ apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.  I've just stumbled on PPA (Personal Package Archive) am I on the right track or is there a better solution?

---- Edit: additional information ---

This is the type of error I'm getting

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
Err http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main liberror-perl all 0.17-1.1   
  503  Service Unavailable 
Err http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main rsync amd64 3.1.1-3  
  503  Service Unavailable 
Unable to correct missing packages. 
E: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libe/liberror-perl/liberror-perl_0.17-1.1_all.deb
  503  Service Unavailable

E: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/rsync/rsync_3.1.1-3_amd64.deb
503  Service Unavailable

E: Aborting install.
```

and update is not able to reach everywhere it wants to either

```
:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources                                          
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages   
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en                                                                        
Hit http://packages.cloud.google.com cloud-sdk-jessie InRelease                                                                          
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease                                                                             
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease                      
Hit http://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-compute-jessie InRelease    
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease                                             
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg                            
Hit http://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-jessie InRelease
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg                                             
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports Release.gpg                  
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release                                
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates Release                        
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports Release                                            
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main Sources/DiffIndex                                       
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex                               
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex                             
Hit http://packages.cloud.google.com cloud-sdk-jessie/main amd64 Packages                           
Hit http://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-compute-jessie/main amd64 Packages                
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                      
Hit http://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-jessie/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://packages.cloud.google.com cloud-sdk-jessie/main Translation-en_US                        
Ign http://packages.cloud.google.com cloud-sdk-jessie/main Translation-en                           
Ign http://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-compute-jessie/main Translation-en_US             
Ign http://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-compute-jessie/main Translation-en                
Ign http://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-jessie/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.cloud.google.com google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en_US                                       
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en_US         
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.66 80]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en                                                                             
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages                                                                             
  404  Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.66 80]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en_US                                                                        
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages                                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.66 80]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main Sources                                                                                  

Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en                                                                           
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main Sources                                                                                            

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources                                                                                    

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main Sources                                                                                  

Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main Sources                                                                                            
  503  Service Unavailable
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources                                                                                    
  503  Service Unavailable
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-backports/main Sources                                                                                  
  503  Service Unavailable
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources  503  Service Unavailable                               

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.66 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/source/Sources  503  Service Unavailable

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.66 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/source/Sources  503  Service Unavailable

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 128.31.0.66 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: `rabbitmq-server` is in Debian, so you can install it with just downloads from `debian.org`.

Comment: It must be the dependencies that are not in debian.org then

Comment: No, Debian is self-contained. All the dependencies of packages from Debian proper are in Debian proper. The only case where this wouldn't be true is if you've enabled third-party repositories that ship packages with the same name as packages from Debian proper, in which case, don't do that. Your question stands for packages that you do want to install and that you can't access directly, whatever they are, it's just that the example you gave isn't a good one.

Comment: Can you access the internet through a proxy? Most intranet setups allow this.

Comment: Perhaps, but wouldn't this circumvent the white-listing that has been done.  A classic example of "your users are your biggest IT risk" :P